# How to replace a string with underscore in edittext and make only underscore editible

Tags: android

Hi guys I am new to android and I am trying to develop and hangman app. I want to replace the character with '__' , for example in case of "apple" I want to have something like "a_pl_" .

I have used edittext to get the string and used replace function to replace the character in a string with '_' but its not working.I am stuck without any idea can anyone help me.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    puztext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.puztext);
    words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.puzzlewords);

    Random rand = new Random();

    puztext.setText(words[rand.nextInt(words.length)]);

    String str = puztext.getText().toString();

    str.replace(' ', '_');
    puztext.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: You said "to replace the character in a string with '_' but its not working" what exactly not working ? what are you getting ? do all of the string turned in to _ _ _ _ and you want only some of them to turn ?or is it something else ?kindly elaborate

Comment: all i am getting is the string itself, like for apple its returning apple. No character is replaced with '_'

Answer (score 1):

use an existing letter for replace. and check it, maybe  there is no space in your input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array is populated with words that contain spaces, the replace(' ', '_') call should actually replace those with underscores.

Are there any spaces in there? Obviously i assume that you don't intend to replace just spaces but rather certain characters within the words, for obfuscation.

Comment: yes. u r correct. I want to replace  random character with '_',not only space.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this;

```
     String str = puztext.getText().toString();
     for(int i = 0; i <(any size you want); i++){
         int randomChar = rand.nextInt(str.length());
         str.replace(str.subString(randomChar, randomChar +1 ), '_');
     }
```

I think thats the algorith that you want.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. I altered the code little and  got what i want.   `for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
            int randomChar = rand.nextInt(str.length());
            str=str.replace(str.charAt(randomChar),'_');
        }
        puztext.setText(str);`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your comment in response to mine 
you said

> all i am getting is the string itself, like for apple its returning
>   apple. No character is replaced with '_'

–

to fix the issue you mentioned in your comment you need to replace this line

```
str.replace(' ', '_');
```

by this

```
str  = str.replace(' ', '_');
```

this will do the replacement.

This is not you main issue though  , you will need to add a logic to your application by selecting some random characters and replace them with _
and store these characters in some array to see if the user make the right choices